# Customize printing properties in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I need to print some pictures in asp.net page and I need to print every picture in a separate page. How can I do this using ASP.net C#?

When I use window.print() it prints the whole page, but I need just the images and also every image in a separate page!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define some things in your stylesheet (.css) file:

```
@media all
{
  .page-break { display:none; }
}
@media print
{
  .page-break { display:block; page-break-before:always; }
}
```

Then, in your HTML, whenever you'd like a page break:

```
<div class="page-break"></div>
```

You can hide/show elements in your print layout the same way (by using `@media print` and setting `display:none` on any element you don't want to print. For example, to only display images in a print layout, this might work (untested):

```
@media print
{
   * { display:none; }
   img { display:block; } 
   .page-break { display:block; page-break-before:always; }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I do not have much experience in CCS even so some how I understand but if there is any sample it will be very helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: I added a sample for the bottom part. For the page breaking, simply put that line `<div class="page-break"></div>` after each image and it should work fine. Make a new stylesheet, include it in your HTML file, and then copy the first block of code into it.